# Why is the color of my element not accurate?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, html5-canvas, line

I have a streamlined wind map (see https://earth.nullschool.net/ for what it is supposed to look like).

I have a weighted interpolation for the point every 10ms and it creates a uVector and a vVector, which then calculates that speed. Based on that speed, a corresponding color is assigned to that point as below.

```
            if (weightWS < 13) {
                color = "#ffa500"
            }
            if (weightWS < 10) {
                color = "#CCCC00"
            }
            if (weightWS < 7) {
                color = "#008000"
            }
            if (weightWS < 4) {
                color = "#0000ff"
            }
            if (weightWS < 1) {
                color = "#800080"
            }
```

The color then gets sent to the animate function. It is in `drawData[3]`.

```
        function animate(){
            //This changes the opacity of the canvas
            ctx.beginPath(); 
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            ctx.closePath();
            //This is where the point is created.
            for(var pointCount=0;pointCount<pointNum;pointCount++){
                let xMid,yMid;
                let xPoint = points[pointCount][0];
                let yPoint = points[pointCount][1];
                if(xPoint < 141 || xPoint >580 || yPoint < 120 || yPoint > 524){
                    xPoint = getRandomIntInclusive(141,580);
                    yPoint = getRandomIntInclusive(120,524);
                    points.push([xPoint,yPoint]);
                }
                //ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                var drawData = weightAllData(xPoint,yPoint); //output: speed, uVec, vVec, color
                colorArr[pointCount] = drawData[3]; //assign color to array, for QA purposes
                
                ctx.moveTo(xPoint, yPoint);
                ctx.lineTo(xPoint+drawData[1],yPoint+drawData[2]);
                ctx.strokeStyle = drawData[3]; //assign the color to the strokeStyle
                //console.log(ctx.strokeStyle); //prints color
                ctx.stroke(); //makes line.
                points[pointCount][0] = xPoint+drawData[1];
                points[pointCount][1] = yPoint+drawData[2];
                //console.log(drawData[0])
         }
```

Although the console shows different colors, mainly `"#800080"` and `"#0000ff"`, the color is affecting all of the points, and the points that have a speed of 1+ still has a color of purple (`"#800080"`).

The color should only be affecting one pixel at a time, and I am positive that some blue points (`"#0000ff"`) should be showing. If a blue point shows, it is all of the pixels at once, which is not the goal.

This happens no matter what speed the animation is at (e.g. 10ms, 1000ms, 10000ms). Does anyone have any solutions or inklings of what the problem is?

Thank you so much for all of your help. I really appreciate the time and effort spent.

Comment: You code is a little inefficient. Could be cleaned up starting with smallest and using if and else if.

Comment: Add the call `ctx.beginPath()` inside the for loop just above the line `ctx.moveTo(xPoint, yPoint);` As you have it you are drawing the same path every iteration of the for loop, thus that final color is the color all line segments will be, beginPath ensures you start a new path every iteration rather than add to the existing path.

Comment: @Blindman67 That worked!!! Oh, thank you so much. If you want to add that as an answer, I will accept it! Thank you!!

Comment: @epascarello I know. I am was trying to make sure that I could even do this project before I made it more efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside the for loop you are adding path segments to the same path.

For example the following snippet has two loops. The first adds 100 path segments to one path. All the lines are redrawn each time `stroke()` is called. All the path segments are drawn in the last color used. Also it is very inefficient, the top loop ends up drawing 5050 line segments, 1st pass draws 1 line, 2nd pass draws 2 more, 3rd pass draws 3 more (3rd pass 6 lines already drawn) and so on.

The second loop starts a new path inside the loop and each path segment get a different color, and there are only 100 line segments drawn.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
const colors = ["Green", "Blue", "Red", "Black", "Yellow"];

ctx.beginPath();              // start a new path
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = colors[i % colors.length];
    ctx.moveTo(i * 5, 0);    // adds to existing path
    ctx.lineTo(i * 5, 40);
    ctx.stroke();            // draw all path segments since last beginPath
}


for (let i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = colors[i % colors.length];
    ctx.beginPath();         // start a new path
    ctx.moveTo(i * 5, 60);   // adds to the path
    ctx.lineTo(i * 5, 100);
    ctx.stroke();            // draw the path
}
```

```css
canvas {boarder: 2px solid #000}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
```

Generally whenever you change the style, line width, etc you need to start a new path.

Answer (score 0):

They need to be else ifs not if but I would probably use ranges as variables instead of multiple if statements as well. But using your code,
this might work:

```
if (weightWS <= 13 && weightWS > 10) {
            color = "#ffa500"
        }
        else if (weightWS <= 10 && weightWS > 7) {
            color = "#CCCC00"
        }
        else if (weightWS <= 7 && weightWS > 4) {
            color = "#008000"
        }
        else if (weightWS <= 4 && weightWS > 1) {
            color = "#0000ff"
        }
        else if (weightWS <= 1 && weightWS > 0) {
            color = "#800080"
        }
        else {
            color = "#000000")
        }
```

If this works I recommend setting variables like purple = [0, 1]

Comment: There is no range function in JavaScript. Do you have any other advice?